# help in understanding steps in product measure question

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $v$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $v$ has no atom. Let $\left(x^{i, N}\right)_{1 \leq i \leq N}$ be the sequence of real numbers defined by:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x^{1, N} & \left.=\inf \{x \mid v((-\infty, x]) \geq \frac{1}{N+1}\right\} \\
x^{i+1, N} & =\inf \left\{x \geq x^{i, N} \mid v\left(\left(x^{i, N}, x\right]\right) \geq \frac{1}{N+1}\right\} \quad 1 \leq i \leq N-1 .
\end{aligned}
$$, so
$$
-\infty<x^{1, N}<x^{2, N}<\cdots<x^{N, N}<+\infty
$$.
How last line follows from second last line, I couldn't manipulate, we have two case with $i< j$ and $i=j$,  can someone help me. Thank you.
$\begin{aligned} \sum_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq N-1} \log \left(x^{j+1, N}-x^{i, N}\right) v^{\otimes 2}\left(x^{i, N} \leq x \leq x^{i+1, N} ; x<y ; x^{j, N} \leq y \leq x^{j+1, N}\right) \\ =\frac{1}{(N+1)^2} \sum_{i<j} \log \left|x^{i, N}-x^{j+1, N}\right|+\frac{1}{2(N+1)^2} \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \log \left|x^{i+1, N}-x^{i, N}\right| .\end{aligned}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For $i<j$: in that case notice that
  $$\left\{ x^{i,N}\leq x \leq x^{i+1,N}; \, x<y;\, x^{j,N}\leq y \leq x^{j+1,N}\right\} = \left\{ x^{i,N}\leq x \leq x^{i+1,N};\, x^{j,N}\leq y \leq x^{j+1,N}\right\}.$$
  (In other words, we can remove the condition $x<y$ as it is implied by $x\leq x^{i+1,N}$ and $y\geq x^{j,N}$).
  Now we can compute its measure
  $$ \begin{align} v^{\otimes 2}\left( x^{i,N}\leq x \leq x^{i+1,N}; \, x<y;\, x^{j,N}\leq y \leq x^{j+1,N}\right) &= v^{\otimes 2}\left( x^{i,N}\leq x \leq x^{i+1,N};\, x^{j,N}\leq y \leq x^{j+1,N}\right)\\&=v(x^{i,N}\leq x \leq x^{i+1,N}) v(x^{j,N}\leq y \leq x^{j+1,N})\\
  &=\frac{1}{(N+1)^2}.
  \end{align}$$
- For $i=j$: we need to compute
  $$v^{\otimes 2}\left(x^{i,N}\leq x<y \leq x^{i+1,N}\right).$$
  To do this, observe that you can write the set $[x^{i,N},x^{i+1,N}]^2$ as the disjoint union
  $$\left\{x^{i,N}\leq x<y \leq x^{i+1,N}\right\}\cup \left\{x^{i,N}\leq y<x \leq x^{i+1,N}\right\}\cup\left\{x^{i,N}\leq x=y \leq x^{i+1,N}\right\}.$$
  Thus taking the measures, we get
  $$\frac{1}{(N+1)^2} = 2v^{\otimes 2}\left(x^{i,N}\leq x<y \leq x^{i+1,N}\right)+v^{\otimes 2}\left(x^{i,N}\leq x=y \leq x^{i+1,N}\right).$$
  Finally the last term is zero because $v$ has no atomes (you can see this using Fubini's theorem).

Comment: Thank you so much. The case of i=j confused me before, but it is clear now.

Comment: @Document123 glad if it helps. If this answers your question please accept the answer.

Comment: sorry, but I don't know how to accept the answer, I am new user, trying to figure out.

Comment: @Document123 https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers